# How to use lost, autoprefixer and postcss-flexibility?

Tags: webpack, postcss, autoprefixer

I want to know the order in which we should use `autoprefixer`, `lost`, `postcssflexibility` in `webpack` ?

Comment: Are you finding variable outcome from changing the order?

Comment: No. Not any intended ones. If I keep the plugins in the general order, they are not throwing errors while compiling but the grids (using lost) are not showing properly in ie9.

Here's the order, in which I'm adding the plugins:

```postcsspartialimport, postcssmixins, postcssnested, postcsssimplevars, lost, autoprefixer, postcssflexibility```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example (prefixing through postcss, applying precss plugin etc.).

### webpack 1

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const precss = require('precss');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss'],
      },
    ],
  },
  // PostCSS plugins go here
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
  },
};
```

### webpack 2

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss', // Needed for now
            plugins: function () {
              // Set up plugins here
              return [
                require('autoprefixer'),
                require('precss'),
              ];
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
},
```

Another way would be to push the plugins to **postcss.config.js** as instructed in the [postcss-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-loader) documentation. It is more difficult to compose that, though.

[Source](http://survivejs.com/webpack/handling-styles/loading/).

Comment: is this webpack 1.x or 2.x ?

Comment: I added webpack 2 example so you can compare and adjust as needed. It's more complicated for sure.

Comment: tried your webpack 1 config still can't solve my case. would you mind have a look at [How to use autoprefixer with Webpack 1.x.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41934519/802365)?