# How to use autoprefixer with Webpack 1.x.x?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, postcss, angular-components, autoprefixer

I'm writing an Angular `1.5.x` app with components that embed their own style. The `<leave-calendar>` component define a `linear-gradient` background which works fine on Firefox but need the vendor prefix in Chromium. Here is what I have done so far:

#### Requirements

1. a working component ;
2. installed `postcss-loader`:

   ```
   yarn add --dev postcss-loader
   ```
3. add `browserslist` to `package.json`:

   ```
   "browserslist": [
       "> 1%",
       "last 2 versions",
       "ie 9"
   ]
   ```

#### `leave-calendar.html`

```
<style lang="scss">
    .leave-draft {
        background-color: #f0ad4e;
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff3 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #fff3 50%, #fff3 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
    …
</div>
```

### Config

#### `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
};
```

#### `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        publicPath: '/static/',
        filename: 'app.min.js'
    },    
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./src'),
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'},
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
        ]
    }
};
```

#### Question

Running my local server with :

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

I don't get the vendor prefix as I expected to. Did I miss something in my config ?

Comment: related [How to use lost, autoprefixer and postcss-flexibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36409464/802365)

Comment: It could be an order issue. Instead of `postcss-loader!sass-loader` I would try `sass-loader!postcss-loader`. Try reducing the configuration as much as possible till you get the plugin running (also validate it runs!).